# Adding linked SQL Server but stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have two Azure instances of SQL Server. Trying to link them together so that I can combine both databases in queries.

All instructions I read uses the stored procedure `sp_addlinkedserver` however I don't seem to have this procedure on either server:

[image]

[image]

Is this a procedure that I should have to add myself? If so how do I go about doing this? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

My goal is to use a table in both servers in a single query.

Comment: Are your Azure databases single instance or Azure managed instances? I suspect it's only supported on the latter .

Comment: From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15): They are not enabled in Azure SQL Database singleton and elastic pools.

Comment: Ah did not realise that i had a single instance. Dam. Im guessing there is no way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [SMor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926183/smor) and [Tom Knevitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12723767/tom-knevitt) posting your discussion as answer to help other community members.

As per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Linked%20servers%20are%20available%20in%20SQL%20Server%20Database%20Engine%20and%20Azure%20SQL%20Managed%20Instance.%20They%20are%20not%20enabled%20in%20Azure%20SQL%20Database%20singleton%20and%20elastic%20pools.%20There%20are%20some%20constraints%20in%20Managed%20Instance%20that%20can%20be%20found%20here.)

> Linked Servers (Database Engine) are not enabled in Azure SQL Database
> singleton and elastic pools.